# Averaging lists of values with duplicate keys

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, numpy

I have gene expression data that I represent as a list of genes and a list of lists of values. I average the expression data for any genes with the same name.

For example:

```
genes = ['A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A']
vals  = [[2.0, 2.0, 9.0, 9.0], # A: will be averaged with row=4
         [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0], # C: will be averaged with row=2
         [8.0, 8.0, 2.0, 2.0], # C: will be averaged with row=1
         [4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0], # B: is fine
         [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]] # A: will be averaged with row=0
```

is converted to

```
genes = ['A', 'B', 'C']
vals  = [[1.5, 1.5, 5.0, 5.0],
         [4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0],
         [5.5, 5.5, 2.5, 2.5]]
```

Here is my function:

```
def avg_dups(genes, values):
    """Finds duplicate genes and averages their expression data.
    """
    unq_genes = np.unique(genes)
    out_values = np.zeros((unq_genes.shape[0], values.shape[1]))
    for i, gene in enumerate(unq_genes):
        dups = values[genes==gene]
        out_values[i] = np.mean(dups, axis=0)
    return (unq_genes, out_values)
```

This function is slower than any other part of my data pipeline, taking 5-10 seconds when other steps that also operate on the whole dataset take sub-seconds. Any thoughts on how I can improve this?

Comment: On an average about how many unique items can be present in genes?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, ~20,000.

Comment: Can you give realistically sized and distributed example data? It helps a ton when trying to optimize.

Comment: @Veedrac, that's hard to answer because there is a lot of variance in the data. Here is an example dataset: ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE43nnn/GSE43805/soft/. The leftmost column, `ILMN...`, needs to be converted to gene symbols, of which there are only 20,000[1], so I suspect there will be quite a few duplicates. [1]There are many more than 20,000 gene symbols, but I convert them to a subset for humans.

Comment: @gwg I don't really mind what the values of the floats are; just the shape of the array and the number of duplicates (approximately).

Comment: Also I don't know what to do with `soft` files.

Comment: I was trying to indicate that the shape and cleanliness of the data can vary significantly. I have seen both 10KB and 20GB files, shapes ranging from (400000,3) to (1000,20), and duplicates ranging from 0 to >75%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be the fastest so far:

```
import numpy
from numpy import newaxis

def avg_dups(genes, values):
    folded, indices, counts = np.unique(genes, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)

    output = numpy.zeros((folded.shape[0], values.shape[1]))
    numpy.add.at(output, indices, values)
    output /= counts[:, newaxis]

    return folded, output
```

This finds the unique genes to fold the values into, along with the `current index → new index` mapping and the number of repeated values that map to the same index:

```
    folded, indices, counts = np.unique(genes, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
```

It adds the row from each current index to the new index in the new `output`:

```
    output = numpy.zeros((folded.shape[0], values.shape[1]))
    numpy.add.at(output, indices, values)
```

`numpy.add.at(output, indices, values)` is used over `output[indices] += values` because the buffering used in `+=` breaks the code for repeated indices.

The mean is taken with a simple division of the number of repeated values that map to the same index:

```
    output /= counts[:, newaxis]
```

Using Ashwini Chaudhary's `generate_test_data(2000)` (giving a 10000x4 array), my rough timings are:

```
name             time/ms  Author
avg_dups           230    gwg
avg_dups_fast       33    Ashwini Chaudhary
avg_dups_python     45    Ashwini Chaudhary
avg_dups           430    Veedrac
avg_dups             5    Veedrac with Jaime's improvement
```

Comment: You can do `folded, indices, counts = np.unique(genes, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)` and spare yourself all those broadcasting comparisons, which typically cripple performance. On the other hand, nice use of `add.at`!

Comment: @Jaime Blimey, that's fast indeed. +1

Comment: @Veedrac, this is very fast. Thanks! Averaging duplicates in my test SOFT file (originally picked at random) using my original function took `5.22903513908` seconds. Your function took `0.000233888626099` seconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your current approach is slow because it takes \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ time, for each unique gene you're checking for its index in `genes`.

One not-pure NumPy approach that I can think of will take \$\mathcal{O}(n \log n)\$ time for this (explanation in comments).

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count
import numpy as np


def avg_dups_fast(genes, values):
    # Find the sorted indices of all genes so that we can group them together
    sorted_indices = np.argsort(genes)
    # Now create two arrays using `sorted_indices` where similar genes and
    # the corresponding values are now grouped together
    sorted_genes = genes[sorted_indices]
    sorted_values = values[sorted_indices]
    # Now to find each individual group we need to find the index where the
    # gene value changes. We can use `numpy.where` with `numpy.diff` for this.
    # But as numpy.diff won't work with string, so we need to generate
    # some unique integers for genes, for that we can use
    # collections.defaultdict with itertools.count. 
    # This dict will generate a new integer as soon as a
    # new string is encountered and will save it as well so that same
    # value is used for repeated strings. 
    d = defaultdict(count(0).next)
    unique_ints = np.fromiter((d[x] for x in sorted_genes), dtype=int)
    # Now get the indices
    split_at = np.where(np.diff(unique_ints)!=0)[0] + 1
    # split the `sorted_values` at those indices.
    split_items = np.array_split(sorted_values, split_at)
    return np.unique(sorted_genes), np.array([np.mean(arr, axis=0) for arr in split_items])
```

Also a Pure Python approach that will take only \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ time. Here I've simply used a dictionary with the gene as key and the corresponding values are going to be appended in a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import izip


def avg_dups_python(genes, values):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in izip(genes, values):
        d[k].append(v)
    return list(d), [np.mean(val, axis=0) for val in d.itervalues()]
```

Timing comparisons:

```
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> from itertools import islice, product

>>> def generate_test_data(n):
        genes = np.array([''.join(x) for x in  islice(product(ascii_letters, repeat=3), n)]*5, dtype='S3')
        np.random.shuffle(genes)
        vals  = np.array([[2.0, 2.0, 9.0, 9.0], # A: will be averaged with row=4
             [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0], # C: will be averaged with row=2
             [8.0, 8.0, 2.0, 2.0], # C: will be averaged with row=1
             [4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0], # B: is fine
             [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]*n) # A: will be averaged with row=0
        return genes, vals
... 

>>> data = generate_test_data(20000)
>>> %timeit avg_dups(*data)
1 loops, best of 3: 18.4 s per loop
>>> %timeit avg_dups_fast(*data)
10 loops, best of 3: 166 ms per loop
>>> %timeit avg_dups_python(*data)
1 loops, best of 3: 253 ms per loop
>>> (avg_dups(*data)[1] == avg_dups_fast(*data)[1]).all()
True
```

Comment: "we need to generate some unique integers for genes" → If they need to be unique, you should avoid `hash` - it does not guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: @Veedrac Interesting! So, two different strings can hash to same value in a given process(considering strings have their own `__hash__` method)?(Python 2.7)
A simple alternative will be to use `d = defaultdict(count(0).next)`, this will return a unique value each time a new string is encountered.

Comment: Yes, the whole point of hashing a string is that the hash is short. Loss of information is inevitable, hence collisions.

Comment: @JanneKarila You're right, not sure what I was thinking. :/

Comment: @JanneKarila: Hash collisions don't take place due to "loss of information", but due to the fact that we do not have a *perfect* hash function --i.e. a hash function that guarantees that no two inputs will *ever* be mapped/hashed to the same output.

Comment: @ray Yes, but *why* don't we have a perfect hash function that maps arbitrary strings to a fixed number of bits? I think the easiest counterargument is about the bits of information.

Comment: @JanneKarila: I think I should've said "not using" instead of "not have" in my earlier post. I did some brief reading and it seems there're perfect hash functions that are very application-specific. Still, I did not find the issues to be related to "loss of information" as you originally stated. Can you provide a reference if you think I'm missing something?

Comment: @ray A perfect hash function can be constructed for a set of strings that is known in advance, see [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html#Motivation). A perfect hash function of *arbitrary strings* would be a powerful lossless data compressor, but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression#Limitations